# En Argentina, ¿qué es "cargar" o "estar cargando"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, hispanoamérica, argentina

Hace unos días leí [una noticia](http://www.marca.com/futbol/premier-league/2016/10/11/57fcef59e5fdea885f8b458f.html) en la que comentaban que un jugador de fútbol se mosqueó un poco con el entrenador por quitarles el acceso a internet.

El jugador es argentino y el titular dice:

> Agüero, cuando Pep quitó el wifi: "Me estás cargando..."

En los comentarios, alguien comentó:

> En ARGENTINA decir cargando quiere decir q [sic] le esta gastando una broma

Así que me dirigí a Asihablamos.com para ver que en Argentina se explica [*cargar*](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Cargar.php?pais=AR) como:

> Tomar a alguien para la joda. Tomar el pelo.

Entonces me pregunto: ¿cuál es el origen de la expresión para referirse a gastar una broma? ¿en qué contexto se usa? ¿se entiende en otros países? Yo en España lo he oído en el sentido de generar molestias (como se indica en los comentarios), pero nunca en el contexto de *bromear*.

Comment: Puede que no sea algo de Argentina. La acepción 13 (¡de 46!) dice que "[cargar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7XB9iU3)" significa "incomodar, molestar o cansar a alguien" y no está marcada como regionalismo. De hecho, a mí no me suena rara...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo tenéis razón. Añado referencias que quedaron en el tintero, donde se indica la utilización como sinónimo de _estar tomando el pelo_.

Comment: Ahora queda más claro. Además, buscando en el CREA aparecen muchos textos con la expresión "¿Me estás cargando?", todos de Argentina. En esos contextos sí que significa "¿Me estás tomando el pelo?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el sentido de "cargar" en la frase de tu ejemplo es una evolución de la acepción 13 del verbo:

> **[cargar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7XB9iU3)**
>
> Del lat. vulg. *carricāre*, y este der. del lat. *carrus* 'carro'.
>
> 13. tr. coloq. Incomodar, molestar o cansar a alguien.

A fin de cuentas, las bromas pueden ser pesadas y llegar a incomodar e incordiar a la gente. El ejemplo más antiguo que he encontrado en el CORDE es del autor argentino Carlos Gorostiza, en su obra "El puente" de 1949:

> Ronco: Y te rajan del laburo.
>
> Tilo: ¿Por qué?
>
> Ronco: Y... porque no hay trabajo...
>
> Ñato: ¡Claro! ¡Psss!
>
> Tilo: ¿Y por qué?
>
> Ronco: ¿Y por qué qué?
>
> Tilo: ¿Por qué no hay trabajo?
>
> Ñato: Y... porque no se vende tanto como antes...
>
> Tilo: ¿Y por qué?
>
> Ñato: ¡Che, **estás cargando**, al final!

En este caso, la expresión sí que hace referencia a la acepción 13. Aunque es curioso verla expresada de forma general ("estás cargando") más que dirigida a una persona en concreto ("me estás cargando"). La expresión tal cual la he visto como muy pronto en [una entrevista de 1973](http://www.magicasruinas.com.ar/revistero/esto/revdesto215b.htm) realizada en Argentina a Ringo Bonavena:

> -¿Vos estudiaste?
>
> -Toda la primaria
>
> -¿Dónde?
>
> -Por todo el barrio.
>
> -¿Y cómo andabas con tu madre?
>
> -**¿Me estás cargando?** Mi madre es el ser más bueno que hay sobre la Tierra. El más dulce. [...]

Se podría interpretar como que la pregunta ha molestado al entrevistado, dado que el entrevistador estaba haciendo la pregunta en serio sin ánimo de hacer una broma. El símil en España podría ser "¿Te estás quedando conmigo?". Es fácil interpretar la frase como "este tipo tiene que estar bromeando si me hace una pregunta como esa, porque si no está bromeando me está cargando (molestando)". Con el tiempo, la idea que queda en la mente ha sido la de "Estás de broma, ¿no?" que contiene la expresión, y por eso se interpreta como que alguien le está tomando el pelo. Me animaría a decir que se usa cuando la tomadura de pelo es de mal gusto y "carga" (molesta) al destinatario.

Answer (score 2):

Me estás cargando =

- ¿Me estás tomando el pelo?
- ¿Es broma? o ¿Es joda? (Más argentino)

¿Se entiende en otros países?

- Sinceramente no.

Ejemplo:

- Juan: Che, te tiré la computadora a la basura.
- Mariano: Posta? (En serio), me estás cargando!?

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Concisa, con detalle y con ejemplos. Gracias y bienvenido a [spanish.se] :)

Answer (score 2):

En Argentina actualmente se dice "¿Me estas cargando?" como quien dice "¿Me estas embromando?", o sea ser objeto de bromas, o mejor, de burlas. "Me estas jodiendo", hace referente a "Joda", que es jarana, divertimento y festejo.

Si profundizamos un poco mas sobre el origen de "cargando", esto viene de algunas cuantas décadas atrás, cuando una persona era objeto de burlas repetidas y esta sentía que se acumulaban o "cargaban" sobre si esas bromas.
El siguiente ejemplo lo explica lo anterior: "Dale, seguí cargándome que yo aguanto", en referencia a ser quien recibe todas las bromas.